# How can I get Kubernetes Service to Expose my Deployment On GKE using a reserved IP address?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a deployement on google cloud kubernetes engine

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: graph-service-2-deployment
  labels:
    app: graph-service-2
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: graph-service-2
      tier: web
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: graph-service-2
        tier: web
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: graph-service-container
          image: gcr.io/myimage:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 1000m
              memory: 2Gi
              ephemeral-storage: 4Gi
            requests:
              cpu: 500m
              memory: 512Mi
              ephemeral-storage: 1Gi
```

I am trying to expose this deployement using Service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: graph-service-2-service
  labels:
    app: graph-service-2
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: 35.212.191.164
  selector:
    app: graph-service-2
    tier: web
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
```

My App listens on 8080.

How I reserved the ip:

`gcloud compute addresses create graph-service-2-ip --region us-west1 --network-tier=STANDARD`

`gcloud compute addresses describe graph-service-2-ip --region us-west1`

I apply the configurations

`kubectl apply -f service`

`kubectl apply -f deployment`

The deployment comes up ok.

I can see my Ip Adresss in Google Cloud VPC Ip Adresses UI, interestingly it says it is not in use:
[image]

Expectation:
Go to the reserved external IP from my web browser and communicate with my app over http.

Actual:
I go to my reserved IP address from my web browser and I am met with the following error page:
[image]
This page didn't send any data.

I also followed google's guide [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/configuring-domain-name-static-ip#step_2b_using_an_ingress) and tried many variations of what they suggested.

**If I create and expose a service via the ui with the same port forwarding rules, it works just fine** and I am able to access my app.

Please let me know why I cannot access my application using my reserved IP.
If you also have any suggestions on how I can improve my setup in other ways I would be happy to hear them.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the static IP you reserved uses the standard network tier.
You'll need to add the following annotation to your service spec:

```
cloud.google.com/network-tier: Standard
```

Something like

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: graph-service-2-service
  labels:
    app: graph-service-2
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/network-tier: Standard
...
```

Note:  You can find all the possible parameters [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/service-load-balancer-parameters)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Gari. 
Adding this annotation lets me access my deployment!